# separate n bits color planes in numpy or skimage

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tiff, scikit-image

I managed to quantize+dither an image in a way that the color index of each pixel has a 8 bits binary representation like ccmmyykk where each of the inks (CMYK) that will be used to print it is coded in 2 bits per pixel.

How can I split the numpy array of uint8 into 4 arrays corresponding to each of the inks, ideally in the format needed to save them as separate 2 bits/pixel tiffs ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`skimage.external.tifffile.imsave`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.external.tifffile.html#skimage.external.tifffile.imsave) and [`numpy.bitwise_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) like this:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.external.tifffile import imsave, imread

 # Mock image used for testing
img = np.asarray([[0b00011011, 0b01101100],
                  [0b10110001, 0b11000110]], dtype=np.uint8)

inks = {'C': 6, 'M': 4, 'Y': 2, 'K': 0}

for i in inks:
    power_of_two = 2**inks[i]
    layer = np.bitwise_and(img, 0b11*power_of_two)//power_of_two
    filename = 'ink-%s.tif' % (i.lower(),)
    imsave(filename, layer)
```

The inks are encoded as 2-bit integers and saved in separate tiffs as `uint8`.

**DEMO**

```
In [10]: img
Out[10]: 
array([[ 27, 108],
       [177, 198]], dtype=uint8)

In [11]: imread('ink-c.tif')
Out[11]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]], dtype=uint8)

In [12]: imread('ink-m.tif')
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 0]], dtype=uint8)

In [13]: imread('ink-y.tif')
Out[13]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [0, 1]], dtype=uint8)

In [14]: imread('ink-k.tif')
Out[14]: 
array([[3, 0],
       [1, 2]], dtype=uint8)
```